# Is message in the Broker not timestamped?

Tags: java, mqtt, iot, paho

I am playing with a IoT project, so far so good, I can share data between Clients using a free broker I found on the web...

My Use case is about a Temperature sensor that is publishing the msg with retention to a topic **room/temp**

Since the msg is retained, a *client_2* is comming latter, makes a subscription to that topic and get the last value of the temp that *client_1* published a while ago.

Now to my question:

I need that *Client_2* gets aswell when was that message published, I mean I would like to know how many seconds later am getting that information..

I am Using Paho-Eclipse as jar and in the callback [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallback.html)

```
messageArrived(java.lang.String topic, MqttMessage message)
```

is nothing about that

why?
How can I?

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

MQTT is an intentionally light weight protocol, that means that there is no un-needed information included in the message header.

A time stamp is not a required field to deliver a message so it's not included.

If you want to include a time stamp then you will have to encode it into the message payload yourself.

Comment: I think adding a timestamp value to the payload is not going to change the hole ***light weight*** concept...

Comment: Given a time stamp normally needs 32bit (4 bytes) and a MQTT header can be as small as 7 bytes for a published message it is very significant

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending the temperature sensor data as JSON data or XML or just plain text?

If you are using JSON then you could do:

```
{"ts":1451649600512, "values":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}}
```

Or XML, you could do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Temperature>
  <TS>1451649600512</TS>
  <Values>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
  </Values>
</Temperature>
```

Comment: just plain text... sending only the value actually, like 11.5 or -2.4